# Devo usar int_least8_t ou int_fast8_t?

Tags: c++, desempenho, tipagem

Estou estudando os limites de tipos que o c++ 11 trouxe e observei que existe oficialmente vários tipos de inteiros.

Além da declaração comum `int` agora eu posso declarar:

- int8_t
- int_fast8_t
- int_least8_t

Nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5254321/4223775) tem uma explicação boa de cada tipo.

Considerando uma plataforma em que o `int` tenha tamanho de 10 bits.O tipo `int8_t` não conseguiria ter exatamente 8 bits.

O que é melhor para eu escolher, `int_fast8_t` ou `int_least8_t`?

Comment: Existe alguma plataforma em uso com byte de 10 bits?

Comment: Não sei dizer. Conheço poucas arquiteturas. A pergunta é mais teórica do que prática. Estou curioso em saber as regras que estão envolvidas em toda a tomada de decisão do compilador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade, até que tenha um motivo para escolher alguma coisa diferente de `int`, deve escolhê-lo.

Se quer usar um `char`, use-o. Ele tem sempre 1 byte. E duvido que encontre uma plataforma ativa que que o byte seja diferente de 8. Certamente nenhum é menor que 7, ou C padrão não pode funcionar, afinal ele precisa poder representar pelos menos 95 caracteres diferentes. E seria o único caso onde o `int_fast8_t` não seria um `char`, mas na prática isso não existe.

Lá na pergunta fala que o `int_least8_t` é sempre um `char`. Ele pode ser usado para dar uma semântica diferente e indicar com mais clareza que ali não é um `char` e sim um inteiro com pelo menos 8 bits. Na prática muda nada.

Quer escolher para que? Sem uma definição do problema, qualquer solução **pode** ser boa.

Se vai desenvolver para várias plataformas e precisa garantir que em todas tenham a melhor performance possível para o inteiro de pelo menos 8 bits quase sempre será um `int`. Eu não "perderia tempo" e usar algo assim se não for comprovado que é absolutamente necessário.

C e C++ exigem que o `int` tenha pelo menos 16 bits e não pode ser maior que o `long int`. Se realmente tiver 10 bits, a implementação não é padrão, então qualquer coisa pode acontecer de acordo com a vontade do implementador, mas na prática não é mais a linguagem C ou C++.

Em tese cada implementador da linguagem pode colocar o que quiser nesses tipos para cada plataforma que ele gere código, desde que obedeça a regra da especificação, e estar dentro do padrão. Na dúvida escolherão o `int` que é bem comum, mas não obrigatório ser do tamanho da palavra do processador.

Na verdade, a pergunta é mais imaginária do que teórica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Fiz uma pequena edição na pergunta para mudar o tipo de char para int. Poderia editar sua resposta de acordo?

Comment: Editei, mas talvez tenha piorado :)

Comment: Não tem problema, acredito que ficou melhor, ainda mais destacando que esse problema é mais teórico que prático.

Answer (score 3):

> O que é melhor para eu escolher, `int_fast8_t` ou `int_least8_t`?

- `int_least8_t` é **o menor** tipo inteiro com pelo menos 8 bits, deve escolhê-lo se se prioriza espaço (memória)
- `int_fast8_t`é o **mais rápido** tipo com pelo menos 8 bits, deve escolhê-lo se prioriza tempo (performance)

Estas definições estão presentes para explicitar as intenções ao escolher o tipo. Uma biblioteca matemática que requer alta performance pode preferir o `int_fast8_t`, e uma biblioteca que precisa guardar muitos dados pode preferir o `int_least8_t`. Como ambos tipos garantem 8 bits de precisão, o programador tem certeza que pode realizar cálculos na faixa `[-128, 127]` com o `int_fast8_t`, e registrar valores entre `[-128, 127]` com o `int_least8_t`.

Na maioria dos processadores pessoais (onde costumo programar) ambos tipos mapeiam para o `signed char`, mas supondo que eu desenvolva um programa e depois desejo portá-lo para outra plataforma (como compilar um jogo para algum celular ou video-game), o compilador (ou programador) pode alterar o tipo `int_fast8_t` para algum mais rápido no novo processador, aumentando a performance das funções matemáticas sem alterar o funcionamento do código nem outras partes do programa.

---

*(isso pode soar óbvio para quem fala inglês, mas expandir o nome dos tipos ajuda:)*

- `int_least8_t` : `tipo_inteiro_pelo_menos_8`
- `int_fast8_t` : `tipo_inteiro_rápido_8`

Comment: Você meio que respondeu a mesma coisa que a pergunta no SOen. Mesmo assim dei +1 por complementar a pergunta e servir de referencia caso mais algum usuário tenha dúvida.

Comment: @jlHertel pena ter ficado muito parecido (não era a ideia), mas esse é o motivo pelo qual os tipos foram inventados/definidos.

Comment: Se é um int não-unsigned, o máximo não seria 127 em vez de 255? (supondo complemento de 2)

Comment: @marcus sim! Corrigido!